# How to change cell value binded in gridview based on condition using asp vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have problem on changing cell value binded in gridview based on condition. The data was binded first to gridview from a csv file. What I want to do is whenever a specific cell on a specific column meets the condition I put, it will change the value of that specific cell.

For example, if cell value is equal to "PHP" then it will changed into "Philippines".
I tried below codes on Gridview RowDataBound event but nothing happens:

```
 Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim myVal As String = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text
        If myVal = "PHP" Then
            GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text = "Philippines"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event for GridView1, then `GridView1_RowDataBound` will be executed **for each row**, not just once. Here's what you should do instead:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim myVal As String = e.Row.Cells(0).Text
        If myVal = "PHP" Then
            e.Row.Cells(0).Text = "Philippines"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's bound to a CSV you have two options:

1. Either change the data in the CSV and rebind it or
2. Instead of binding the table to the CSV, just input the data from the CSV and then you will be able to change the table independently from the CSV.

If you want to change both the CSV and the table choose option 1. If you don't care about the CSV and or want to create a separate output then choose option 2.

*edited to add some code

You just read it into the table like normal. Since it's a CSV I would personally just change it to a .txt file to make it easier. Then:

```
dim reader as string() = input.txt

for x as integer = 0 to reader.length -1
    dim split as string() = reader(x).split(","c)

    for y as integer from 0 to split.length - 1
       datagridview.cells(y+1,x+1) = split(y)
    next
next
```

This is untested, but it should go together something along these lines (I don't know the format of the CSV). If you have uneven rows it would probably be better if you did something like this

```
for each str as String in Split
    add to datagrid...
next
```

Comment: but sir it's not ideal because the csv file comes from a url address, i cannot change the data.

Comment: Then instead of binding the data, just import the data. By Binding the data you are saying that the two objects are going to be the same 100% of the time (they are bound). So if you just import the data, then you can change one without needing to affect the other.

Comment: sir can you post some codes on how can I import the csv data from url address? if it's ok for you